# How to use Pipes in Ionic 2 (release v2.2.1)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I wanted to use Pipe to sort some data as provided [here](https://github.com/nicolas2bert/angular2-orderby-pipe/blob/master/app/orderby.ts).

The above looks consistent with the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html), i.e. we have the following imports and class definition:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'exponentialStrength'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent: string): number {
    let exp = parseFloat(exponent);
    return Math.pow(value, isNaN(exp) ? 1 : exp);
  }
}
```

So, in the above we import from `Pipe` and `PipeTransform` and then we derive our class from `PipeTransform`.

Using the Ionic generator, e.g. `ionic g pipe testPipe` I notice different imports, and also it does not implement the `PipeTransform`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'test-pipe'
})
@Injectable()
export class TestPipe {
  transform(value, args) {
    value = value + ''; // make sure it's a string
    return value.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

So it does not extend `PipeTransform`? Anyway, so going on, I tried to use it, so I try to add it to my component.

```
import { TestPipe } from '../../pipes/test-pipe';

@Component({
  pipes:[TestPipe],
  selector: 'my-page',
```

and I get this TypeScript error:

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ pipes: typeof TestPipe[]; selector: string;
templateUrl: string; animations: AnimationEntryM...' is not assignable
to parameter of type 'Component'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not
exist in type 'Component'.`
```

Any one have any ideas here? The doco for the pipes does not seem to match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the release version of Angular 2, the [`@Component` decorator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html) does not include a `pipes` property. Instead, you should add your custom pipe to your application or feature `NgModule`'s `declarations`:

```ts
import { TestPipe } from '... pipes/test-pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestPipe,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
class AppModule {}
```

With it added to the `NgModule`'s `declarations` there is no need to import it into your component's module; just use it in the component's template.

Comment: That works 100%! So event the Angular doco is a little out of date. Now just to get the sort pipe working (it is being called but my items are not sorted - but that's another issue)